# cannot set a correct content-type for downloaded pdf in android

Tags: android, pdf, types

I cannot open a pdf that i download from the web:

In first activity class i set the intent type like this:

```
> Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SecondClassActivity.class);
myIntent.setType("application/pdf");
```

I get to the second class activity that has the logic for downloading the pdf from an URL.
I set the path to where to be downloaded, i open an url connection and set the contenty type like this:

> URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
>         connection.setDoOutput(true);
>         connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
>          connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
>         connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=" + filename);
>         connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "UTF-8");
>          connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.5; en-US; rv:1.9.0.13) Gecko/2009073021 Firefox/3.0.13");
>   connection.connect();

But when i read what type of content type i have:

`System.out.println("Connection type : " + connection.getContentType());`
the answer is: `text/html`... :(

And of course i cannot open the pdf with adobe, i get and error saying "Unable to open this file". I think it's because the content type is not correct.

Does anyone got into this error before? I looked at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378238/downloaded-pdf-with-java-is-corrupt) but still does not work... Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

The type you set for the Intent has nothing to do with the content type set in the URLConnection object.

Comment: Downloading the file and saving it on sdcard, should it be enough? i am not creating a pdf, just writing the bytes.

Comment: this did the trick http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576513/android-download-binary-file-problems.